# Как добавить значок сортировки на заголовок ListView используя MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

Примеров сортировки по столбцам ListView с отображением треугольника в какую сторону идёт сортировка, я нашёл достаточно. Но они все подразумевают использование Code-behind, где выбирается нужный нам GridViewColumnHeader и уже туда вешается соответствующий значок.
Но как того же добиться используя MVVM я не разобрался :(. Прошу помощи.
Итак есть  ListView

```cs
<ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan ="2" ItemsSource ="{Binding FoldersInfo}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DirNumber}">
                <GridViewColumn.Header>
                    <GridViewColumnHeader CommandParameter="1" Command="{Binding Sorted}">Номер Папки</GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn.Header>                       
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CountOfFile}">
                <GridViewColumn.Header>
                    <GridViewColumnHeader CommandParameter="2" Command="{Binding Sorted}">Кол-во файлов</GridViewColumnHeader>
                </GridViewColumn.Header>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileNum}">
                <GridViewColumn.Header>
                    <GridViewColumnHeader CommandParameter="3" Command="{Binding Sorted}">Номер файла</GridViewColumnHeader>
                </GridViewColumn.Header>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}">
                <GridViewColumn.Header>
                    <GridViewColumnHeader CommandParameter="4" Command="{Binding Sorted}">Путь</GridViewColumnHeader>
                </GridViewColumn.Header>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

И код сортировки

```cs
public RelayCommand Sorted  => new RelayCommand(o =>
{
    if (FoldersInfo == null || FoldersInfo.Count == 0) return;
    if (lastSorted.Equals(o.ToString())) sortUp = !sortUp;
    else sortUp = true;
    FoldersInfo = lg.sorted(FoldersInfo, o.ToString(), sortUp);
    lastSorted = o.ToString();
});
```

А как добавить значки сортировки ума не приложу :(. И было бы совсем замечательно, если бы подсказали как это сделать через темы.

Comment: Ну наверное в GridViewColumnHeader вам надо не просто текст добавить, а ещё и нужную иконку, т.е. вместо `Кол-во файлов` пишите `<Grid><Image .../><TextBlock Text="Кол-во файлов" /></Grid>`

Comment: Картинку вставить это даже не пол дела, а десятая часть. Нужно же сделать так, что бы она пявлялсь только в том столбце по кторому прошла сортировака и в определённом направлении.

Comment: Ага, а эту информацию храните в VM, обновляйте ее в вашей `RelayCommand Sorted`

Comment: Ну логику решения данной проблемы я понял, спасибо. Хотя такое решение мне вовсе не нравиться. Ведь как я понял мне понадобиться дополнительные 4 переменные (по количеству столбцов) и уже эти переменные менять в зависимости от того на какой столбец нажали для сортировки. Хотелось бы решить данную задачу через стили/темы. Но пока и на этом спасибо.

Comment: В любом случае вам эту информацию (по какому столбцу и в какую сторону сортировка) надо где-то хранить, стилями/темами не обойтись. Хранить не обязательно в четырех переменных — можно и в одной (enum с атрибутом Flag, например), просто нужно будет написать конвертер, который поможет вам для каждого столбца понять надо ли выводить для него иконку или нет

Comment: В том то и дело, что как то можно. Вот тут: https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/themes/DarkBlue_UI/theme_db.php можно скачать тему для интерфейса. И там кода на С# практически нет, всё написано на XAML. И в DataGrid там всё прекрасно сортируется и ставятся нужные значки. Но как они это делают я так и не смог разобраться :(. Мне проще (понятнее) всё это в коде написать. Но факт остаётся фактом, значки они как то добавили через тему.

Comment: В DataGrid сортировка по столбцу — это штатный функционал, который работает и без сторонних тем (см. свойство `CanUserSortColumns`), в ListView такого функционала штатно нет

Comment: Понятно, значит буду кодить.